# User can't RDP into her PC

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Multiple users are not able to RDP into their PCs. Users get "The connection was denied because the user account is not authorized for remote login."  I went to computer, properties, advanced system settings, click on the remote tab, the Allow connections from computers... radio button is highlighted, and added her name is there. The next day she reports that she can't get in.  I check the remote desktop user setting her name is gone again.  Her name is over ridden with a group of users who do have RDP member.  I did put the users part of RDP membership but their names keep disappearing. I also did GPMC computer configuration, policies, windows settings, security settings, restricted groups, and added them there and still their name clears. What can I do to make their names stick.

Comment: Is this a Windows 10 environment?

Comment: No.  Windows 7 64 bit.  Servers are Windows 2008 R2

Comment: If you go into File explorer, right click on "this PC" click manage, then go to local users and groups > groups, are they a member of the built in Remote desktop users group? If yes, try making them a local admin on their machine just to see if they can remote in while an admin.

Comment: The user wasn't on there.  It was an old list of RDP users.  I deleted the list and added her. I will see what happens.  I will keep you posted.

Comment: Given the symptoms you describe, the most likely cause is domain group policy.  Quick test: add the user to the group (either directly or via the Remote tab on System Properties) then run gpupdate.  If running gpupdate always makes the user disappear from the list, the problem is group policy.

Comment: going into the remote desktop users worked for a little while now the problem is reoccurring.  Where is the group policy that I can adjust?